# Supporting .sh version scripts for migration

Tags: flyway

This is what I found about Flyway supporting `.sh` scripts:

> ##### Script migrations
>
> **Flyway Teams**
>
> Sometimes it may be more desirable to use a scripting language for
> migrations. Flyway Teams currently supports the `.ps1`, `.bat`,
> `.cmd`, `.sh`, `.bash`, `.py` file extensions as migrations, and on
> non-windows platforms it also supports migrations without extensions
> (assuming a valid shebang).
>
> These migrations follow the same naming scheme as SQL migrations, with
> only the file extension being different. For example
> `V1__execute_batch_tool.ps1` is a valid migration.

[Source](https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/flyway-cli-and-api/concepts/migrations#Migrations-Scriptmigrations)

But when I tried such a script:

```
user@server (A) :flyway-9.12.0$ vi dodavky/V2__20230720_vytvoreni_tabulky_pres_sqlplus.sh
#!/bin/bash
# Database credentials
DB_USERNAME="xxx"
DB_PASSWORD="xxx"
DB_HOST="xxx"
DB_PORT="xxx"
DB_SID="xxx"
# SQL statement to create the table
SQL_CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE flyway_test_sqlplus (
                  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
                  name VARCHAR2(50),
                  age NUMBER
                 );"
# Construct the sqlplus command
SQLPLUS_CMD="sqlplus -S ${DB_USERNAME}/${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_SID}"
# Execute the SQL statement using sqlplus
echo "Executing SQL statement..."
echo "${SQL_CREATE_TABLE}" | ${SQLPLUS_CMD}
# Check the exit status to see if the command was successful
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Table created successfully."
else
    echo "Table creation failed."
fi
```

It ran into an error:

```
ERROR: Unable to parse statement in dodavky/V2__20230720_vytvoreni_tabulky_pres_sqlplus.sh at line 1 col 1. See https://rd.gt/3ipi7Pm for more information: No value provided for placeholder: ${DB_USERNAME}.  Check your configuration!
Caused by: No value provided for placeholder: ${DB_USERNAME}.  Check your configuration!`
```

It looks like Flyway still tries to interpret it as SQL, not bash.

Does Flyway allow different suffixes than `.sql`, but still expect the content in SQL? I have proper values instead of xxx records in my script.